# "Your Communities" list showing incorrect Meta SO reputation score

Tags: bug

My Communities list is showing an incorrect reputation score for Meta Stack Overflow.  As you can see, I have 130 reputation, but this screenshot:

[image]

is showing that I only have three!  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Blame caching...

Comment: Relevant MSE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation